# What do I do wrong in my php upload script?

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

So, today I tried to make a PHP upload script, I caught a problem... It doesn't upload the file, I looked where the problem could be & I got that something is wrong with the `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_file)){` line, need your help guys

```
if(isset($_POST['but_upload'])){
       $maxsize = 5368706371; // 5GB

       $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
       $target_dir = "videos/";
       $target_file = $target_dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
       $id = generateRandomString();

       // Select file type
       $videoFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

       // Valid file extensions
       $extensions_arr = array("mp4","avi","3gp","mov","mpeg");

        // Check extension
      if( in_array($videoFileType,$extensions_arr) ){

          // Check file size
          if(($_FILES['file']['size'] >= $maxsize) || ($_FILES["file"]["size"] == 0)) {
            echo "File too large. The file must be less than 5GB.";
          }else{
            // Upload
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_file)){
              echo ("working!");
            }
          }

      }else{
          echo "Invalid file extension.";
      }

     }
     ?>
<!doctype html>
<head lang="en">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <input type="submit" name="but_upload">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

generateRandomString function is in another file

**EDIT:**
error.log tells me that:

```
[06-Oct-2019 16:26:49 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(videos/VSkzuJn0aZYoLvNLJwv3IrFNA9PV1zjfd4MfoXP3rjl1Nm7uW8--Peek 2019-05-20 18-11.mp4): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/myacc/website.com/index.php on line 34

[06-Oct-2019 16:26:49 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpTOsPRj' to 'videos/VSkzuJn0aZYoLvNLJwv3IrFNA9PV1zjfd4MfoXP3rjl1Nm7uW8--Peek 2019-05-20 18-11.mp4' in /home/myacc/website.com/index.php on line 34
```

Comment: can you be more specific with details of the problem?  Are there errors? Does anything happen? Does it timeout if the file is too large? Is error reporting enabled?

Comment: rather than a relative path to the `videos` directory I'd suggest using the fully qualified path and see if that helps

Comment: @RamRaider nope, the same error accures

Comment: can you show the new path? I see you edited the question but not sure what I'm looking at above ( if newest path or previous )

Comment: @RamRaider wasnt me,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `videos/` as the path suggests that the upload folder is within the current working directory and whilst that might work experience has shown me that using the full path has always proven more reliable - so perhaps this might help?

```
$target_dir = __DIR__ . "/videos/";

if( !file_exists( $target_dir ) ){
    mkdir( $target_dir, 0777, true );
    clearstatcache();
}

$target_file = $target_dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];// ... etc as before
```

Comment: what is cleanstatcache()?

Comment: oops - that should be clearstatcache. `"PHP caches the information certain functions return in order to provide faster performance"` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: man you are a hero, thank you a lot, it works, idk why it didn't

Comment: no problems, glad it helped. Consider accepting as a solution perhaps?!